# Could not find gradle flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I created a new flutter project by VS Code. but I don't know why I am got this error on run

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar
  > - https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.pom
  > - https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.2/gradle-3.6.2.jar

I searched a lot for the gradle problem but I can't see any solution

I installed Android studio, Android SDK 29, Flutter SDK and VS code plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to open the android folder with AndroidStudio and let Gradle to download android dependencies.

**solution**:
if some countries have been banned maybe you need to use some VPN to download these dependencies. Hotspot shield is a good option cause it will change the IP address of your machine.

Comment: I tried to run the project with Android studio but I got the same error

Comment: maybe you have to use VPN for downloading files.

Comment: Psiphon don't change your os IP. use something that changes your  ip

Comment: Any example app !!??

Comment: search it in google you can find several options. and I used Hotspot shield

Comment: I think Syria is banned so I have to use proxy. Some articles says that I can set proxy settings in the project files like gradle.properties

Comment: Has any one sample of proxy settings or any articles that help ?

Comment: thanks you're right, the problem was in Psiphon, Because of Syria is banned I had to use another VPN (Hotspot shield) to solve my problem You can post an answer to mark it as solutions please, stay safe