# How to fix "Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1" error when i run flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, sdk

**"Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1"**

I make a new basic flutter project, and I got this error when I run flutter doctor everything is well, no issues detected. I have tried flutter clean, and try to rebuild and the messages are the same.
anyone can help me please to fix this problem.

error:

[image]

Flutter doctor:

[image]

logcat:

[image]

device connected:

[image]

Module Window:
[image]

Comment: first of all please open android module in Android studio and then run app it shows some relative error in logcat

Comment: i already updated logcat pict.

Comment: image does not contains any emulator information and real device so please first connect with real device or emulator then update the pic

Comment: my phone is connected, but in logcat showing "no connected device".. i updated picture

Comment: I am talking about Logcat window of Android Studio

Comment: can't connect to any device, my phone not detected :(

Comment: have you update flutter recently?

Answer (score 3):

Open your android folder with the android studio it'll help you to find out whats the issue. also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61228212/9689717) too.

Comment: can you tell me the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

Use `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`

Comment: i already do this and still error :( do you know how to uninstall without any setting saved? i want to try reinstall maybe can solved this problem

Comment: all. flutter and android studio, include android sdk and flutter sdk

Comment: please check new pict.

Comment: Which OS is there on your system?

Answer (score 0):

I got same error code a few days ago when I try to run all my Flutter projects. To make sure you encounter the same problem as I did;

First, go to your project directory -> open android folder -> check if there's a `gradlew.bat` file inside. `<project_name>\android\gradlew.bat`. If there's no such file, then you can follow along.

Here's what I did:

1. Run `flutter create -t <project_name>`, by using this command, it will ensure that there will be `gradlew.bat` file inside the project.
2. Go to that project directory `<project_name>\android`, copy that `gradlew.bat` file.
3. Paste it to the same directory path (`<project_name>\android`) of one of your current not-working Flutter project.
4. Try to run the `flutter run` command on that project.

Comment: Hope that works for you. I tried some other things before doing that steps but I don't think they are relevant. Later if you've tried above steps and still doesn't work, I will edit my answer to provide all things I tried.

Comment: Ok i will try it